# c# Collision detection with moving object

Tags: c#

I have made a block move using visual studio with my arrow keys and want it to stop moving when it comes in contact with another block (wall). I got it working for the side collisions but the top and bottom aren't working.

```
if(player.Right >wall.Left && player.Left < wall.Right - player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > wall.Top && player.Top < wall.Bottom)
{
    right = false;
}
else if (player.Left < wall.Right && player.Right > wall.Left + player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > wall.Top && player.Top < wall.Bottom)
{
    left = false;
}
else if (player.Left < wall.Right && player.Right > wall.Left + player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > wall.Top && player.Top < wall.Bottom)
{
    up = false;
}
```

I have deleted the down movement because it wasn't working but it was the same as the up key. Can someone please help me with this issue. ( i have set up,down,left,right as Boolean variables)

Comment: The condition in the third branch is exactly the same as the one in second branch. You will never enter it.

Comment: Use [Rectangle.IntersectsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=netframework-4.8) Method instead and cancel the move if the method returns `true`. So `if(player.IntersectsWith(wall)) { //don't move... }` otherwise move the player object. The same concept is implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482551/vb-net-movement-blocked-due-to-faulty-collision-detection/59485657#59485657).

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!