# Add points when PictureBox1 hits PictureBox2

Tags: vb.net, timer, location, picturebox

I'm trying to make a simple game using VB.Net and its concept is like egg catching.

My expectation is that when the egg is falling (`PictureBox1`), the catcher (`PictureBox2`) catches the egg and it gets 1 point every catch. My idea is when the location of egg matches the location of the catcher it adds point. But it didnt work. Any suggestion here?

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Top += 5

    If PictureBox1.Location.Y = PictureBox2.Location.Y Then
        score += 1
        Label1.Text = score

    End If

End Sub
```

And this is the code for game over:

```
 Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If PictureBox1.Location.Y > 400 Then
        Me.Dispose()
        MsgBox("game over")
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Better to use a single drawing canvas (like `PictureBox`) and handle the `Paint` event to draw everything. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485657/10216583).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!  I believe the Bounds property should work for this.
Also, may want to just use a boolean (or raise an event) for the collision, so this way you're not doing the work twice.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Top += 5
    Dim itHappened as Boolean

    Dim other_boxes as New List(Of PictureBox) from {PictureBox2} ', PictureBox3, PictureBox4}
    For each box in other_boxes
         If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(box.Bounds) Then
                    score += 1
                    Label1.Text = score
                    itHappened = True                  
         else
                itHappened = False 'depending on your logic, may not be the best place
         End If
    Next


    If PictureBox1.Location.Y > 400 Then
        Me.Dispose()
        MsgBox("game over")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Bounds.IntersectsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: what if i had many to catch atleast 3? and the condition goes on til i havent catch one of them?

Comment: Yes if you're adding more I'd suggest not using the boolean and having the `.IntersectsWith` checks in 1 spot, either way.  If it is running twice on each tick, it will slow down dramatically.

Comment: @Kimmy here's a more flexible version using a list, but if you plan to have a lot, I suggest not hard-coding the list and having objects add themselves or pull from settings or a .config file.

Comment: its still the same

Comment: How so?  There must be something I can't see as this works on my end.  Run a test, instead of setting the .Top in the timer - try to just drop 1 on top of the other, run the code, and see if that fires.  If so, then it's where the image is moving.

Comment: The game is over when the PictureBox goes out of bounds, not when they hit right?  I've updated my answer - it's all in 1 timer to keep it simple.

Comment: it works now. thanks man. I changed the location of the eggs everytime it matched the catcher so that it wont keep on adding score.

Comment: @Kimmy no problemo, and thank you too!  Neat little project :)